# Is coprimality in $NC$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algorithms, computational-complexity, computational-number-theory

Following reference https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e86e/8d7a267a29b9ad4ca112828109adfec55e8b.pdf claims integer coprimality is in $NC$ and it also has one citation. Is this claim valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably it's not valid:

[On ECCC, Comment #3 to TR98-009](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/1998/009/) | 11th May 2001 12:33
Comment on parallel complexity of coprimality

Referee Report of SICOMP submission

...
**Recommendation**
The paper is not acceptable for publication. The algorithm contains a 
flaw I believe to be fatal. In fact, I do not think that the author's approach, though innovative and promising at first sight, is viable.
...